# Set height to child div to match parent in > Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I'm slowly moving an app from Angular 1.x to Angular 5 and hoping that there is a better solution to this.

I am using a virtual infinite scroll and in Angular 1.x I used the code:

```
getListHeight: function () {
    return {
        height: '' + ($window.innerHeight - 64) + 'px'
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that the *virtual scroll container needs a numerical value and not a % or auto or inherit* in order to calculate how many items can be shown at a single time. Is there a better way to do this in > Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get height of any element by using `#LocalVarible` and the use it like `{{ getHeight.offsetHeight }}`

```
<p #getHeight>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
  <br/>
  Wow
</p>
Height of above tag : {{ getHeight.offsetHeight }}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-element-height)**

Comment: This is the method I used. The code I used is as follows:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-element-height-kuodqr